# Complex MongodbDB query in Mule4

Tags: mongodb-query, mule4

I am trying to make a Mongodb query in Mule with the $in function, but mule says Invalid input '$', expected Namespace or NameIdentifier

have a collection that stores user authorization

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584a0dea073d4c3e976140a9"),
    "partnerDataAccess" : [ 
        {
            "factoryID" : "Fac-1",
            "partnerID" : "Part-1"
        }
    ],
    "userID" : "z12",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584f5eba073d4c3e976140ab"),
    "partnerDataAccess" : [ 
        {
            "factoryID" : "Fac-1",
            "partnerID" : "Part-2"
        }, 
        {
            "factoryID" : "Fac-2",
            "partnerID" : "Part-2"
        }
    ],
    "userID" : "w12",
}
```

the flow will submit a userID and partnerID and query the database to see if authorization exist

when I query from Robo 3T, I write queries like this

e.g. user w12 and partner Part-2

```
db.getCollection('user').find({
    userID:"w12", "partnerDataAccess.partnerID": {$in : ["Part-2", "ALL"]}
    })
```

The $in was used because there is the "ALL" setting for admins

but while I try to put the `find` part into the Mongodb connector, Mule gives error during development and runtime

Hardcoded:

```
        <mongo:find-one-document collectionName="user" doc:name="Find one document" doc:id="a03a6689-6b9d-473c-b8a6-3b8d1e989e38" config-ref="MongoDB_Config">
            <mongo:find-query ><![CDATA[#[{
    userID:"w12",
     "partnerDataAccess.partnerID": {$in : ["Part-2", "ALL"]}
}]]]></mongo:find-query>
        </mongo:find-one-document>
```

parametized

```
        <mongo:find-one-document collectionName="user" doc:name="Find one document" doc:id="a03a6689-6b9d-473c-b8a6-3b8d1e989e38" config-ref="MongoDB_Config">
            <mongo:find-query ><![CDATA[#[{
    userID: payload.User,
     "partnerDataAccess.partnerID": {$in : [ payload.partner, "ALL"]}
}]]]></mongo:find-query>
        </mongo:find-one-document>
```

Error:

during development:
`Invalid input '$', expected } or  ~ or , (line 3, column 38):`
Runtime:

```
Message               : "Script '{
    userID:"w12",
     "partnerDataAccess.partnerID": {$in : ["Part-2", "ALL"]}
} ' has errors: 
    Invalid input '$', expected Namespace or NameIdentifier (line 3, column 38):
 at 3 : 3" evaluating expression:
```

I have tried removing the $ or escaping the $ with backslash but it does not work

I know my query is not actually complex, welcome any help

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

seems to have found the correct way

```
><![CDATA[#[{
    userID:"w12",
     "partnerDataAccess.partnerID": {"\$in" : ["Part-2", "ALL"]}
}]]]>
```