# How to Query date "greater than" in Query Mongodb component in anypoint studio?

Tags: mongodb, mule, anypoint-studio, mule4

When i use the "find documents" component mongodb in mule 4 anypoint studio, i want to find date superiour.

I tried everything

I have tried this :

```
{ date : { $gt: new ISODate('2015-01-01')}}' has errors: Invalid input '$', expected ??? (line 3, column 21): at 3 : 3" evaluating expression: "#[output application/json --- { date : { $gt: new ISODate('2015-01-01')}}]"
```

Comment: Please share the complete operation you are trying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? remember to upvote valid answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58055400/721855

Comment: can you try this { "date": { "$gt": {"$date": "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"} } }

Comment: Hello, i tried what the link aled gave but puting a "\" still makes the error, i also tried what you gaev Anurag Sharma. So what i am trying is to take a date from my mongodb with anypoint studio and to only take date greater than XXXXX.